# How to change the writing in TextBox from right-to-left to left-to-right?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows, winforms

I've recently been struggling with issue that forbids me from writing left-to-right, instead it writes right-to-left. Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
string originalText;
private string replaceToStars(object sender)
{
    if (sender == textBox3)
    {
        originalText = textBox3.Text;

        string replaced = Regex.Replace(originalText, @"[a-z0-9A-Z]", "*");
        textBox3.Text = replaced;
    }
    else if (sender == textBox3)
    {
        textBox3.Text = originalText;
    }
    return textBox3.Text;
}
```

Comment: What relevance does the `replaceToStars` method have? Also, both of the conditions in your `if` and `else if` blocks are the same.

Comment: @Diado what this method does, is actually replacing the given text in "textbox3" with stars "*", also yeah, my bad with "else if" statement but it still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Can't you use `[TextBox].PasswordChar = '*'`? Do you have `[TextBox].RightToLeft = Yes` in the Designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to add this info in the comment. Hence posting this info in answer.

- Right-click on the respective text box and Select **Properties**.
- Under the heading **Appearance** Select the **TextAlgin** dropdown and Select **Left**.

As simple as that, Hope this helps...